# How can I properly use WebCamTexture in Unity iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, camera, aforge

I was recently using the [WebCamTexture API in Unity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WebCamTexture.html), but ran across a couple issues.

My biggest issue is orientation. When I ran the app on my phone, it wouldn't work properly in portrait mode: the image was orientated so it was landscape while the phone was portrait. Rotating the phone didn't help.

Then I changed the default orientation of the app to landscape and it worked, but the image was reflected: letters and such would be backwards in the image. Rotating the image 180 on the y-axis didn't help since it was a 1 sided image.

Here's the code for the camera alone:

```
cam = new WebCamTexture();
camImage.texture = cam;
camImage.material.mainTexture = cam;
cam.Play ();
camImage.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1,-1,1);
```

where camImage is a RawImage.

How would I rotate the image to work correctly in portrait as well as reflecting the image correctly? Am I using the API incorrectly?

Comment: This thread may help: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webcamtexture-rotated-and-flipped-on-iphone-when-applied-to-renderer-material-texture.126702/

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/webcamtexture-rotated-and-flipped-on-iphone-when-applied-to-renderer-material-texture.126702/#post-1439938

I was looking at that solution, but how do I use the shader part of it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

important -

for some years now, it is really only practical to use "NatCam" now for camera work, either ios or droid, in Unity3D - every app which uses the camera, uses it.

There is no other realistic solution, until Unity actually do the job and include (working  :) ) camera software.

---

solution is basically this ...

you have to do this EVERY FRAME, you can't do it "when the camera starts".

Unity f'd up and the actual values only arrive after a second or so.  it's a well-known problem

```
private void _orient()
    {
    float physical = (float)wct.width/(float)wct.height;
    rawImageARF.aspectRatio = physical;

    float scaleY = wct.videoVerticallyMirrored ? -1f : 1f;
    rawImageRT.localScale = new Vector3(1f, scaleY, 1f);

    int orient = -wct.videoRotationAngle;
    rawImageRT.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f,0f,orient);
    showOrient.text = orient.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: **NOTE** just get **NatCam** from the assetStore - it has changed everything